# Select2 not working in Jquery-Steps

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-steps

I installed Jquery-steps plugin and select2 plugin. I put select2 box inside the Wizard form (jquery-steps) and it doesn't work. The list values are not exported in . Outside the wizard select2 works fine.

Answer (score 29):

I just had to set `$('.class').select2();` *AFTER* `$('#form').steps();`

Comment: You mean add all  $("#id").select2({ placeholder: 'PleaseSelect' }).on('change', function(){ ... }); AFTER $('#form').steps(); OR move $('#form').steps(); before you define your select2.

Comment: He meant the order of code should be:

$('#form').steps();
$('.class').select2();

Can confirm this works.